# How to set using default value from "Main Website" for product?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.0

In my system were two store views. "Default Store View" (`store_id=1`) and "Custom Store View" (`store_id=2`). Custom view always was default.
I removed unnecessary store view "Default".

When I programmatically import products it stores values to table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for `store_id=2`.
In my code I don't set any store id. I tried to set but it gives me no result.

So when I want to change product name for "Main Website" it gives me nothing at frontend (there is the same product name as it was, i.e. for `store_id=2`), because it edits value only for `store_id=0` ("Main WEbsite"), but no changes for `store_id=2`.

There no ability to switch for "Custom Store View" for now when it is only one store view in system.

I have single store mode enabled and I need only one store view with only one value type for each product. 
I know that I can cleanup some tables with values for `store_id=2`, but my system does import of products every day, therefore I need to turn off storing values for Custom Store View.

How to do this? Or any other ideas how to fix this?

UPD: Github issue page https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7877#issuecomment-317441253

Comment: did you found the solution?

Comment: @BilalUsean, nothing special. My problem was in import of products, so simply I set needed value of store_id to all of them.

Comment: @BilalUsean, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7877#issuecomment-317441253 maybe it will help you.